# SQL Join if greater than 'out of range'

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

There are `Member` and `Risk` tables with the following columns:

**Member** table:

- ID
- Name
- Gender
- Age

**Risk** table:

- Age
- Gender
- RiskScore

In `Risk` table, each age has associated risk score, but age 60 is the last record because any age above 60 should have the same risk score as the 60 year old.

I want to join those two tables in a query but the below query would show Null risk score where age > 60.

How can I show the risk score for members who are older than 60 in a query?

```
SELECT 
    m.ID, 
    m.AGE,
    r.RiskScore
FROM 
    Member AS m
LEFT JOIN 
    Risk AS r ON r.age = m.age AND ON r.Gender = m.Gender
```

`RiskScores` are different based on `Gender` and `Age`.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result. (Formatted text please.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set member age to 60 if it is greater than 60 using `IIF` function.

```
  SELECT 
        m.ID, 
        m.AGE,
        r.RiskScore
    FROM 
        Member AS m
    LEFT JOIN 
        Risk AS r ON r.Gender = m.Gender AND r.age = IIF(60 < m.age , 60 ,m.age)
```

Comment: Thank you. this was the easiest solution.

Comment: except it should have been: IIF(60 < m.age , 60 ,m.age)

Comment: @inincubus : Thank you. Just slipped through my mind.

Answer (score 2):

did you try this (i didn't)

```
SELECT 
    m.ID, 
    m.AGE,
    r.RiskScore
FROM Member AS m
LEFT JOIN Risk AS r ON r.age = case when m.age >= 60 then 60 else m.age end AND ON r.Gender = m.Gender
```

Comment: I didn't know you can use Case When within Join. Good to know. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Not experienced with SQL server, but it looks like you could do:

```
LEFT JOIN Risk as r on r.age = MIN(60, m.age)
```

Comment: there's no such min function in transact sql

Comment: it looks like there is, though... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/min-transact-sql

Comment: @dave that's the `min()` _aggregate_ function and that only takes a **single** argument (and needs a `group by`)

Comment: Didn't work on SQL Server. would be nice if it does though.